# Show website on one server in subfolder on another server

Tags: redirect, subdomain, alias, directory

I have two websites. One website is a microsite developed by someone else, hosted on a subdomain and I would like to serve this website via a URL on the second website, for example:

test.maindomain.com - This is the website hosted on a seperate server.
maindomain.com/test - This is where I would like to show the website test.maindomain.com.

Is this possible? maindomain.com is hosted on a Lightspeed shared server so access to server config files may be limited.

I should also mention that I need test.maindomain.com to appear as though it resides on maindomain.com/test becuause we want all the SEO value of test.maindomain.com passed to maindomain.com/test.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `<iframe>` tag for that?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: We need it to appear as though it resides on maindomain.com/test becuause we want all the SEO value of test.maindomain.com passed to maindomain.com/test.